# BeautifulSoup: AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Do you know why the first example in BeautifulSoup tutorial http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#QuickStart gives `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'name'`? According to [this answer](http://groups.google.com/group/beautifulsoup/browse_thread/thread/5359ec13be2347d5/2f8fad5e788fe9e0) the space characters in the HTML causes the problem. I tried with sources of a few pages and 1 worked the others gave the same error (I removed spaces). Can you explain what does "name" refer to and why this error happens? Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`name` will refer to the name of the tag if the object is a `Tag` object (ie: `<html>` name = "html")

if you have spaces in your markup in between nodes BeautifulSoup will turn those into `NavigableString`'s.  So if you use the index of the `contents` to grab nodes, you might grab a `NavigableString` instead of the next `Tag`.

To avoid this, query for the node you are looking for: [Searching the Parse Tree](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Searching%20the%20Parse%20Tree)

or if you know the name of the next tag you would like, you can use that name as the property and it will return the first `Tag` with that name or `None` if no children with that name exist: [Using Tag Names as Members](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Using%20tag%20names%20as%20members)

If you wanna use the `contents` you have to check the objects you are working with. The error you are getting just means you are trying to access the name property because the code assumes it's a `Tag`

Answer (score 38):

Just ignore `NavigableString` objects while iterating through the tree:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

for body_child in soup.body.children:
    if isinstance(body_child, NavigableString):
        continue
    if isinstance(body_child, Tag):
        print(body_child.name)
```

Comment: Awesome! Works like charm in 2021! Thank you Max! :)

Comment: your're the man. thx!

Answer (score 9):

You can use try catch to eliminate the cases when Navigable String is being parsed in the loop, like this:

```
    for j in soup.find_all(...)
        try:
            print j.find(...)
        except NavigableString: 
            pass
```

Comment: I got: 
   except NavigableString:
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
when using this

Comment: Instead of try/catch maybe testing for an instance of `NavigableString` is more helpful (as try/catch only works for classes inherited from exception classes):
```python
for child in date.children:
 if isinstance(child, NavigableString):
  text = child.strip()
 else:
  text = child.text.strip()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the latest working code to obtain the name of the tags in soup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

res = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')

for child in soup.body.children:
    if isinstance(body_child, Tag):
        print(child.name)
```