# How to extract a particular Purpose and Name using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written following code

```
    page=requests.get("http://3.85.131.173:8000/random_company") 
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
    info_list=soup.find_all("li")
    print(info_list)
```

and print gives following answer

```
[<li>Name: Walker, Meyer and Allen</li>, <li>CEO: David Pollard</li>, <li>CTO: Sandra Boyd</li>, <li>Address: 275 Jones Station Suite 008
Bradburgh, UT 24369</li>, <li>Investment Round: C</li>, <li>Purpose: Reduced logistical contingency for whiteboard end-to-end applications</li>]
```

I want to extract name and position  earlier I was using indexing but it was dynamic could anyone advise how to extract name and purpose.

My edited code after feedback :

```
page=requests.get("http://3.85.131.173:8000/random_company") 
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
info_list=soup.find_all("li")
print(info_list)
name=[]
purpose=[]
```

I am now able to print name and location successfully. it is giving following output ['Name: Burnett and Sons'] suppose if I want only Burnett and Sons then what should I do? Could any advise?

Comment: loop over the list (`for item in info_list:`) and check `if "Name" in item:`, similarly do for the position

Comment: Do you want to extract all names with their respective positions? Or only the item tagged `'Name'` ?

Comment: Which is it you "want to extract name and position", or "to extract name and purpose" ?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you want to scrape. Please [edit] your question to show the expected output.

Comment: @matiiss-I want to extract name and purpose .I tried below code {         page=requests.get("http://3.85.131.173:8000/random_company") 
        soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
        info_list=soup.find_all("li")
        for item in info_list:
            if("Name" in item):
                print(item)
            } I am getting only one  output that is purpose. .I need name and Purpose .Also I looped for name but it is giving me output as purpose?

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'Name' in item.text:
    name=name.append(item)        <-- Wrong: assigns None to name
if 'Purpose' in item.text:
    purpose=purpose.append(item)  <-- Wrong: assign None to purpose
```

The two above pointed lines are the problem. `list.append()` returns None.
(See futher explanation: [Why does append() always return None in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-always-return-none-in-python))

To get your expected output remove the `name=` part and let `list.append()` add to your lists inline as below:

```
for item in item_list: 
    if 'Name' in item.text:
        name.append(item.text)
    if 'Purpose' in item.text:
        purpose.append(item.text)

print(name, purpose)
```

should print:

```
['Name: Ward and Sons'] ['Purpose: User-friendly mission-critical algorithm for visualize killer e-business']
```

Comment: I do not want position I need name and purpose .Kindly see my code.I am unable to extract name and purpose the info_list variable in my code.Also for extraction I don't want to use index .For example using indexing  info_list[0] will give me name but I don't to hard code it.

Comment: Got it, thanks for explaining, @cmpunk, please see my updated code

Comment: The problem with your code was searching only the Tag element, not the ***text*** within the Tag.

Comment: Thank you both of you for your response.I wanted the same thing but when I ran the full code{page=requests.get("http://3.85.131.173:8000/random_company") 
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,"html.parser")
item_list=soup.find_all("li")
for item in info_list: 
    if 'Name' in item.text or 'Purpose' in item.text:
        print(item)
        
       it is giving me error in if statement error(NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text')

Comment: @cmpunk See how it runs here no errors, press the Blue (>>> Run) button at top-right of page: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/downshift/files/home/downshift/69715704/script.py?edit

Comment: the `NavigableString` errror may be because you're using `page.content`, try using `page.text` instead, I've included it in my answer. Also, see [BeautifulSoup: AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591535/beautifulsoup-attributeerror-navigablestring-object-has-no-attribute-name)

Comment: Thanks I have one more doubt.I need to put Name and Purpose in a separate list and then transfer it to a dataframe.I tried below code  :soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,"html.parser") 
name=[]
purpose=[]
item_list=soup.find_all("li") 


for item in item_list: 
        {
      if 'Name' in item.text:
            name=name.append(item)
      if 'Purpose' in item.text:
              purpose=purpose.append(item)
        }
       Could you advise how to rectify the code.Thanks for your help once again.

Comment: How about two lines: `df['Name'] = name; df['Purpose'] = purpose` ? You've got the two lists, just add them to the DataFrame

Comment: soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,"html.parser") 
name=[]
purpose=[]
item_list=soup.find_all("li") 


for item in item_list: 
        {
      if 'Name' in item.text:
            name=name.append(item)
      if 'Purpose' in item.text:
              purpose=purpose.append(item)
        }
I understand the code that you wrote.My issue is I am unable to separate Name and Purpose using IF statement.   It is giving me error: File "<ipython-input-3-fbd2dea78b1d>", line 9
    if 'Name' in item.text:

Comment: you didn't include what kind of error it is, what is the full text of the Traceback error?

Comment: My code:soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,"html.parser") 
name=[]
purpose=[]
item_list=soup.find_all("li") 


for item in item_list: 
        {
      if 'Name' in item.text:
            name=name.append(item)
      if 'Purpose' in item.text:
              purpose=purpose.append(item)
        }
                                                                                                                                
 Error:{  File "<ipython-input-3-fbd2dea78b1d>", line 9
    if 'Name' in item.text:
    ^]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax}

Comment: You have an error in your syntax, [edit] and post your code in the question above, the code is unclear in comments.

Comment: I have  edited my post.If possible kindly advise.

Comment: You edited ***my*** post.  I needed you to put the code into ***your*** post at the top of page.

Comment: But the problem is you are mixing Java syntax with Python syntax. Curly-braces `{`, `}` in your `if-else` blocks are illegal and not allowed. Remove these from your code: `{`, `}`

Comment: Otherwise, your code should run fine. Remove the curly-braces and try again, and post your results.

Comment: I have edited my post and pasted code after removing brackets.Now it is giving output as None.Kindly advise.

Comment: Thanks @cmpunk, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
targets = ["Name","Purpose"]
for item in info_list:
    if item.text.split(":")[0] in targets:
        print(item.text)
```

Output (in this case):

```
Name: Jimenez LLC
Purpose: Mandatory context-sensitive approach for leverage compelling communities
```